# Error working with COM object from Python throw clr reference - class not registred

Tags: python, com, registry, win32com, solidworks

Trying to make an App for Solidworks.
First tried to use win32com or comtypes to get access to the COM object of solidworks.
Made some progress, but couldnt get it working well.
Found a way to work with clr and interop dlls.
More progress, but now got stuck on this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:  (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {27526253-6119-4B38-A1F9-2DC877E72334} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Python.Runtime.ConstructorBinder.InvokeRaw(BorrowedReference inst, BorrowedReference args, BorrowedReference kw, MethodBase info)
```

my code is:

```
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference("C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS 2019\SOLIDWORKS\SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.dll")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x000001D80F877040>
>>> clr.AddReference("C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS 2019\SOLIDWORKS\SolidWorks.Interop.swconst.dll")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x000001D80F877080>
>>> from SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks import *
>>> from SolidWorks.Interop.swconst import *
>>> swApp = ISldWorks(SldWorksClass())
>>> swApp.Visible=True
>>> modl = IModelDoc2(ModelDoc2Class())
```

Solidworks loads well, can work with it, but got no access to ModelDoc2 object.
All they are in registry (SdlWorksClass, ISldModelDoc2, ModelDoc2Class, IModelDoc2):
Their interfaces are both in registry. TypeLib is registred too.

from registry CLSID:

```
assembly: SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks, Version=27.5.0.72, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c4797c3e4eeac0
class: SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2Class
```

I can see ModelDoc2 object methods: `dir(ModelDoc2)`

As far as I dig the class is registered (cannot test otherwise, any suggestions?)
COMview tool shows me the typelib as CLSID. Tested on two SW versions: 2019 and 2020.

Stuck and cannot continue.
Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG means the COM client (your python code) does not find the COM server's class (using it's CLSID) you're asking for (in the registry). It's often an x86 vs x64 issue (your client is x86 and SolidWorks is registered in x64 registry or the reverse)

Comment: wiered that SldWorks object working well. same typelib, same dll, same app. 
ill try 32b

Comment: tried both python 32bit and 64bit, same error.

Comment: The way you create the object seems over complicated (It seems you go through a .NET interop first?). Why don't you use python usual way to create COM objects. You can use a tool such as ProcMon from sysinternals (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to check what registry calls are made.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried to use regular COM, and It gave me something, but very limited access. Only the main app object (ISldWorks), interop dll gives me much more, but not whole objects. will check ProcMon though. Thanks